# Minimize the sum of errors of representative integers

Tags: arrays, algorithm, optimization, combinations

Given n integers between [0,10000] as D<sub>1</sub>,D<sub>2</sub>...,D<sub>n</sub>, where there may be duplicates, and n can be huge:

I want to find k distinct representative integers (for example k=5) between [0,10000] as R<sub>1</sub>,R<sub>2</sub>,...,R<sub>k</sub>, so the sum of errors of all the representative integers is minimized.

The error of a representative integer is defined below:

Assuming we have k representative integers in ascending order as {R<sub>1</sub>,R<sub>2</sub>...,R<sub>k</sub>}, the error of R<sub>i</sub>
is :
[image]

and i want to minimize the sum of errors of the k representative integers:

[image]

how can this be done efficiently?

**EDIT1:** The smallest of the k representative integers must be the smallest number in 
{D<sub>1</sub>,D<sub>2</sub>...,D<sub>n</sub>}

**EDIT2:** The largest of the k representative integers must be the largest number in {D<sub>1</sub>,D<sub>2</sub>...,D<sub>n</sub>} plus 1. For example when the largest number in {D<sub>1</sub>,D<sub>2</sub>...,D<sub>n</sub>} is 9787 then R<sub>k</sub> is 9788.

**EDIT3:** A concrete example is here:

D={1,3,3,7,8,14,14,14,30} and if k=5 and R is picked as {1,6,10,17,31} then the sum of errors is :

sum of errors=(1-1)+(3-1)*2+(7-6)+(8-6)+(14-10)*3+(30-17)=32

this is because 1<=1,3,3<6 , 6<=7,8<10, 10<=14,14,14<17, 17<=30<31

Comment: I'm sure @Moron is on to something here. Unless I'm missing something, the sum you've got to expands to sum(D) + a sum of the repeated R's. I don't think this is the error formulation you need.

Comment: @Chris: For each Ri, the Dx used are those that `Ri <= Dx` .

Comment: In other words, to calculate error for each Dx, he takes the closest (below Dx) Ri.

Comment: Do you really want R_i <= D_x <= R_i+1? Or did you want R_i <= D_x < R_i+1?

Comment: {0,1,2,3,4} and k=2, R1=R2=0 gives an error of 0. That's less than R1=0, R2=2 which surely is more like what's sought. (I'm guessing the largest R_i must be the largest number, too).

Comment: @Chris: you are right, the largest R_i must be the largest number, i edited.

Comment: Thanks @outlaw - any chance you could clarify what was pointed out by @mhum - it seems in your example that the R's don't have to be in the sequence, but is the right-hand side of the equality inclusive? (It seems to count an extra error term if so).

Comment: @mhum: em, it should be R_i <= D_x < R_i+1 , thanks

Comment: @Chris:i changed the definition, exclusive of the right-hand side of the equality.

Comment: @outlaw thanks so much for the edits... this is now a beautifully clear question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although with help from the community you have managed to state your
problem in a form which is understandable mathematically, you still do
not supply enough information to enable me (or anyone else) to give
you a definitive answer (I would have posted this as a comment, but
for some reason I don't see the "add comment" option is available to
me). In order to give a good answer to this problem, we need to know
the relative sizes of n and k versus each other and 10000 (or the
expected maximum of the D<sub>i</sub> if it isn't 10000), and whether
it is critical that you attain the **exact** minimum (even if this
requires an exorbitant amount of time for the calculation) or if a
close approximation would be OK, also (and if so, how close do you
need to get). In addition, in order to know what algorithm runs in
minimum time, we need to have an understanding about what kind of
hardware is going to run the algorithm (i.e., do we have m CPU
cores to run on in parallel and what is the size of m relative to k).

Another important piece of information is whether this problem will be
solved only once, or it must be solved many times but there exists
some connection between the distributions of the integers D<sub>i</sub>
from one problem to the next (e.g., the integers
D<sub>i</sub> are all random samples from a particular, unchanging
probability distribution, or perhaps each successive problem has as
its input an ever-increasing set which is the set from the previous
problem plus an extra *s* integers).

No reasonable algorithm for your problem should run in time which
depends in a way greater than linear in n, since building a histogram
of the n integers D<sub>i</sub> requires O(n) time, and the answer to
the optimization problem itself is only dependent on the histogram of
the integers and not on their ordering. No algorithm can run in time
less than O(n), since that is the size of the input of the problem.

A brute force search over all of the possibilities requires, (assuming
that at least one of the D<sub>i</sub> is 0 and another is 10000), for
small k, say k < 10, approximately O(10000<sup>k-2</sup>) time, so if
log<sub>10</sub>(n) >> 4(k-2), this is the optimal algorithm (since in
this case the time for the brute force search is insignificant compared to the
time to read the input). It is also interesting to note that if k is
very close to 10000, then a brute force search only requires
O(10000<sup>10002-k</sup>) (because we can search instead over the
integers which are *not* used as representative integers).

If you update the definition of the problem with more information, I
will attempt to edit my answer in turn.

Answer (score 3):

Now the question is clarified, we observe the R<sub>i</sub> divide the D<sub>x</sub> into k-1 intervals, [R<sub>1</sub>,R<sub>2</sub>), [R<sub>2</sub>,R<sub>3</sub>), ... [R<sub>k-1</sub>,R<sub>k</sub>). Every D<sub>x</sub> belongs to exactly one of those intervals. Let q<sub>i</sub> be the number of D<sub>x</sub> in the interval [R<sub>i</sub>,R<sub>i+1</sub>), and let s<sub>i</sub> be the sum of those D<sub>x</sub>. Then each error(R<sub>i</sub>) expression is the sum of q<sub>i</sub> terms and evaluates to s<sub>i</sub> - q<sub>i</sub>R<sub>i</sub>.

Summing that over all i, we get a total error of S - sum(q<sub>i</sub>R<sub>i</sub>), where S is the sum of all the D<sub>x</sub>. So the problem is to choose the R<sub>i</sub> to *maximize* sum(q<sub>i</sub>R<sub>i</sub>). Remember each q<sub>i</sub> is the number of original data at least as large as R<sub>i</sub>, but smaller than the next one.

Any global maximum must be a local maximum; so we imagine increasing or decreasing one of the R<sub>i</sub>. If R<sub>i</sub> is *not* one of the original data values, then we can increase it without changing any of the q<sub>i</sub> and improve our target function. So an optimal solution has each R<sub>i</sub> (except the limiting last one) as one of the data values. I got a bit bogged down in math after that, but it seems a sensible approach is to pick the initial R<sub>i</sub> as every (n/k)th data value (simple percentiles), then iteratively seeing if moving the R_i to the previous or next value improves the score and thus decreases the error. (The q<sub>i</sub>R<sub>i</sub> seems easier to work with, since you can read the data and count repetitions and update q<sub>i</sub>, R<sub>i</sub> by only looking at a single data/count point. You only need to store an array of 10,000 data counts, no matter how huge the data).

```
data:   1  3  7  8 14 30
count:  1  2  1  1  3  1     sum(data) = 94

initial R: 1  3  8  14  31
initial Q: 1  3  1   4        sum(QR)  = 74 (hence error = 20)
```

In this example, we could try changing the 3 or the 8 to a 7, For example if we increase the 3 to 7, then we see there are 2 3's in the initial data, so the first two Q's become 1+2, 3-2 - it turns out this decreases sum(QR)). I'm sure there are smarter patterns to detect what changes in the QR table are viable, but this seems workable.

Answer (score 1):

If the distribution is near random and the selection (n) is large enough, you are wasting time, generally, trying to optimize for what will amount to real costs in time calculating to gain decreasing improvements in % from expected averages. The fastest average solution is to set the lower k-1 at the low end of intervals M/(k-1), where M is the lowest upper bound - the greatest lower bound (ie, M = max number possible - 0) and the last k at M+1. It would take order k (the best we can do with the information presented in this problem) to figure those values out. Stating what I just did is not a proof of course.

My point is this. The above discussion is one simplification that I think is very practical for one large class of sets. At the other end, it's straightforward to compute every error possible for all permutations and then select the smallest one. The running time for this makes that solution intractable in many cases. That the person asking this question expects more than the most direct and exact (intractable) answer leaves much that is open-ended. We can trim at the edges from here to eternity trying to quantify all sorts of properties along the infinite solution space for all possible permutations (or combinations) of n numbers and all k values.

Answer (score 1):

The integrity of this program was partly confirmed by a modified version of it used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6017278/minimizing-time-in-transit) to produce data that matched [results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6017278/minimizing-time-in-transit/6026869#6026869) obtained independently by @mhum.

It finds the **exact** minimal error value(s) and corresponding R values for a given data set and k value(s).

```
/************************************************************
This program can be compiled and run (eg, on Linux):
$ gcc -std=c99 minimize-sum-errors.c -o minimize-sum-errors
$ ./minimize-sum-errors
************************************************************/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//data: Data set of values. Add extra large number at the end

int data[]={
10,40,90,160,250,360,490,640,810,1000,1210,1440,1690,1960,2250,2560,2890,3240,3610,4000,4410,4840,5290,5760,6250,6760,7290,7840,8410,9000,9610,10240,99999,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,24,24,14,12,41,51,21,41,41,848,21,  547,3,2,888,4,1,66,5,4,2,11,742,95,25,365,52,441,874,51,2,145,254,24,245,54,21,87,98,65,32,25,14,25,36,25,14,47,58,58,69,85,74,71,82,82,93,93,93,12,12,45,78,78,985,412,74,3,62,125,458,658,147,432,124,328,952,635,368,634,637,874,124,35,23,65,896,21,41,745,49,2,7,8,4,8,7,2,6,5,6,9,8,9,6,5,9,5,9,5,9,11,41,5,24,98,78,45,54,65,32,21,12,18,38,48,68,78,75,72,95,92,65,55,5,87,412,158,654,219,943,218,952,357,753,159,951,485,862,1,741,22,444,452,487,478,478,495,456,444,141,238,9,445,421,441,444,436,478,51,24,24,24,24,24,24,247,741,98,99,999,111,444,323,33,5,5,5,85,85,85,85,654,456,5,4,566,445,5664,45,4556,45,5,6,5,4,56,66,5,456,5,45,6,68,7653,434,4,6,7,689,78,8,99,8700,344,65,45,8,899,86,65,3,422,3,4,3,4,7,68,544,454,545,65,4,6,878,423,64,97,8778,5456,5486,5485,545,5455,4548,81,999,8233,5223,8741,7747,7756,54,7884,5477,89,332,5999,9861,12545,9852,11452,5482,9358,9845,577,884,5589,5412,3669,32,6699,396,9629,953,321,45,5484,588,5872,85,872,87,1122,884,2458,471,22685,955,2845,6852,589,5896,2521,35696,5236,32633,56665,6633,326,5486,5487,8541,5495,2155,3,8523,65896,3852,5685,69536,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,
};

//N: size of data set

int N=sizeof(data)/sizeof(int);

//SavedBundle: data type to "hold" memoized values needed (minimized error sums and corresponding "list" of R values for a given round) 

typedef struct _SavedBundle {
    long e;
    int head_index_value;
    int tail_offset;
} SavedBundle;

//sb: (pts to) lookup table of all calculated values memoized

SavedBundle *sb;  //holds winning values being memoized

//Sort in increasing order.

int sortfunc (const void *a, const void *b) {
    return (*(int *)a - *(int *)b);
}

/****************************
Most interesting code in here
****************************/

long full_memh(int l, int n) {
    long e;
    long e_min=-1;
    int ti;

    if (sb[l*N+n].e) {
        return sb[l*N+n].e;  //convenience passing
    }
    for (int i=l+1; i<N-1; i++) {
        e=0;
        //sum first part
        for (int j=l+1; j<i; j++) {
            e+=data[j]-data[l];
        }
        //sum second part
        if (n!=1) //general case, recursively
            e+=full_memh(i, n-1);
        else      //base case, iteratively
            for (int j=i+1; j<N-1; j++) {
                e+=data[j]-data[i];
            }
        if (e_min==-1) {
            e_min=e;
            ti=i;
        }
        if (e<e_min) {
            e_min=e;
            ti=i;
        }
    }
    sb[l*N+n].e=e_min;
    sb[l*N+n].head_index_value=ti;
    sb[l*N+n].tail_offset=ti*N+(n-1);
    return e_min;
}

/**************************************************
Call to calculate and print results for the given k
**************************************************/

int full_memoization(int k) {
    char *str;
    long errorsum;  //for convenience
    int idx;

    //Call recursive workhorse
    errorsum=full_memh(0, k-2);
    //Now print
    str=(char *) malloc(k*20+100);
    sprintf (str,"\n%6d %6d {%d,",k,errorsum,data[0]);
    idx=0*N+(k-2);
    for (int i=0; i<k-2; i++) {
        sprintf (str+strlen(str),"%d,",data[sb[idx].head_index_value]);
        idx=sb[idx].tail_offset;
    }
    sprintf (str+strlen(str),"%d}",data[N-1]);
    printf ("%s",str);
    free(str);
    return 0;
}

/******************************************
Initialize and seek result for all k values
******************************************/

int main (int x, char **y) {
    int t;
    int i2;

    qsort(data,N,sizeof(int),sortfunc);
    sb = (SavedBundle *)calloc(sizeof(SavedBundle),N*N);
    printf("\n     Total data size: %d",N);
    printf("\n     k errSUM    R values",N);
    for (int i=3; i<=N; i++) {
        full_memoization(i);
    }
    free(sb);
    return 0;
}
```

Some sample results obtained:

```
 Total data size: 375
 k errSUM    R values
 3 475179 {1,5223,99999}
 4 320853 {1,5223,56665,99999}
 5 260103 {1,5223,7653,56665,99999}
 6 210143 {1,5223,7653,32633,56665,99999}
 7 171503 {1,421,5223,7653,32633,56665,99999}
 8 142865 {1,412,2458,5223,7653,32633,56665,99999}
 9 124403 {1,412,2458,5223,7653,32633,56665,65896,99999}
10 106790 {1,412,2458,5223,7653,9610,32633,56665,65896,99999}
11  93715 {1,412,2458,5223,7653,9610,22685,32633,56665,65896,99999}
12  81507 {1,412,848,2458,5223,7653,9610,22685,32633,56665,65896,99999}
13  71495 {1,412,848,2155,3610,5223,7653,9610,22685,32633,56665,65896,99999}
14  64243 {1,412,848,2155,3610,5223,6633,7747,9610,22685,32633,56665,65896,99999}
15  58355 {1,412,848,2155,3610,5223,6633,7653,8523,9610,22685,32633,56665,65896,99999}
16  53363 {1,65,412,848,2155,3610,5223,6633,7653,8523,9610,22685,32633,56665,65896,99999}
17  48983 {1,65,412,848,2155,3610,4548,5412,6633,7653,8523,9610,22685,32633,56665,65896,99999}
18  45299 {1,65,412,848,2155,3610,4548,5412,6633,7653,8523,9610,11452,22685,32633,56665,65896,99999}
19  41659 {1,65,412,848,2155,3610,4548,5412,6633,7653,8523,9610,11452,22685,32633,56665,65896,69536,99999}
20  38295 {1,65,321,441,848,2155,3610,4548,5412,6633,7653,8523,9610,11452,22685,32633,56665,65896,69536,99999}
21  35232 {1,65,321,441,848,2155,3610,4548,5412,6633,7653,8523,9610,11452,22685,32633,35696,56665,65896,69536,99999}
22  32236 {1,65,321,441,848,2155,3610,4410,5223,5455,6633,7653,8523,9610,11452,22685,32633,35696,56665,65896,69536,99999}
23  29323 {1,65,321,432,634,872,2155,3610,4410,5223,5455,6633,7653,8523,9610,11452,22685,32633,35696,56665,65896,69536,99999}
24  26791 {1,65,321,432,634,862,1690,2458,3610,4410,5223,5455,6633,7653,8523,9610,11452,22685,32633,35696,56665,65896,69536,99999}
25  25123 {1,65,321,432,634,862,1690,2458,3610,4410,5223,5455,5872,6633,7653,8523,9610,11452,22685,32633,35696,56665,65896,69536,99999}
26  23658 {1,65,321,432,634,862,1690,2458,3610,4410,5223,5455,5872,6633,7653,8233,8700,9610,11452,22685,32633,35696,56665,65896,69536,99999}
27  22333 {1,41,78,321,432,634,862,1690,2458,3610,4410,5223,5455,5872,6633,7653,8233,8700,9610,11452,22685,32633,35696,56665,65896,69536,99999}
28  21073 {1,41,78,321,432,634,862,1440,2155,2845,3610,4410,5223,5455,5872,6633,7653,8233,8700,9610,11452,22685,32633,35696,56665,65896,69536,99999}
29  19973 {1,41,78,321,432,634,848,951,1960,2458,2845,3610,4410,5223,5455,5872,6633,7653,8233,8700,9610,11452,22685,32633,35696,56665,65896,69536,99999}
30  18879 {1,41,78,321,432,634,848,951,1960,2458,2845,3610,4410,5223,5455,5872,6633,7653,8233,8700,9358,9845,11452,22685,32633,35696,56665,65896,69536,99999}
31  17786 {1,41,78,321,432,634,848,951,1960,2458,2845,3610,4410,5223,5455,5872,6633,7653,8233,8700,9358,9845,11452,12545,22685,32633,35696,56665,65896,69536,99999}
32  16801 {1,41,78,321,432,634,848,943,1440,1960,2458,2845,3610,4410,5223,5455,5872,6633,7653,8233,8700,9358,9845,11452,12545,22685,32633,35696,56665,65896,69536,99999}
33  15821 {1,41,78,218,321,432,634,848,943,1440,1960,2458,2845,3610,4410,5223,5455,5872,6633,7653,8233,8700,9358,9845,11452,12545,22685,32633,35696,56665,65896,69536,99999}
34  14900 {1,41,78,218,321,421,544,634,848,943,1440,1960,2458,2845,3610,4410,5223,5455,5872,6633,7653,8233,8700,9358,9845,11452,12545,22685,32633,35696,56665,65896,69536,99999}
35  14185 {1,41,78,218,321,421,544,634,848,943,1440,1960,2458,2845,3610,4410,5223,5455,5872,6633,7290,7747,8410,8700,9358,9845,11452,12545,22685,32633,35696,56665,65896,69536,99999}
36  13503 {1,41,78,218,321,421,544,634,741,862,951,1440,1960,2458,2845,3610,4410,5223,5455,5872,6633,7290,7747,8410,8700,9358,9845,11452,12545,22685,32633,35696,56665,65896,69536,99999}
37  12859 {1,21,45,78,218,321,421,544,634,741,862,951,1440,1960,2458,2845,3610,4410,5223,5455,5872,6633,7290,7747,8410,8700,9358,9845,11452,12545,22685,32633,35696,56665,65896,69536,99999}
38  12232 {1,21,45,78,218,321,421,544,634,741,862,951,1440,1960,2458,2845,3610,4410,5223,5455,5664,5872,6633,7290,7747,8410,8700,9358,9845,11452,12545,22685,32633,35696,56665,65896,69536,99999}
39  11662 {1,21,45,78,218,321,412,444,544,634,741,862,951,1440,1960,2458,2845,3610,4410,5223,5455,5664,5872,6633,7290,7747,8410,8700,9358,9845,11452,12545,22685,32633,35696,56665,65896,69536,99999}
40  11127 {1,21,45,78,218,321,412,444,544,634,741,862,951,1440,1960,2458,2845,3610,4410,5223,5455,5664,5872,6633,7290,7747,8233,8523,8700,9358,9845,11452,12545,22685,32633,35696,56665,65896,69536,99999}
41  10623 {1,21,45,78,218,321,412,444,544,634,741,862,951,1440,1960,2458,2845,3610,4410,5223,5455,5664,5872,6633,7290,7747,8233,8523,8700,9358,9610,9845,11452,12545,22685,32633,35696,56665,65896,69536,99999}
42  10121 {1,21,41,65,85,218,321,412,444,544,634,741,862,951,1440,1960,2458,2845,3610,4410,5223,5455,5664,5872,6633,7290,7747,8233,8523,8700,9358,9610,9845,11452,12545,22685,32633,35696,56665,65896,69536,99999}
43   9637 {1,21,41,65,85,218,321,412,444,544,634,741,862,951,1440,1960,2458,2845,3610,3852,4410,5223,5455,5664,5872,6633,7290,7747,8233,8523,8700,9358,9610,9845,11452,12545,22685,32633,35696,56665,65896,69536,99999}
44   9207 {1,21,41,65,85,218,321,412,444,544,634,741,862,951,1440,1960,2458,2845,3610,3852,4410,4840,5223,5455,5664,5872,6633,7290,7747,8233,8523,8700,9358,9610,9845,11452,12545,22685,32633,35696,56665,65896,69536,99999}
45   8804 {1,21,41,65,85,218,321,412,444,544,634,741,862,943,1122,1690,2155,2458,2845,3610,3852,4410,4840,5223,5455,5664,5872,6633,7290,7747,8233,8523,8700,9358,9610,9845,11452,12545,22685,32633,35696,56665,65896,69536,99999}
46   8409 {1,21,41,65,85,218,321,412,444,544,634,741,862,943,1122,1690,2155,2458,2845,3240,3610,3852,4410,4840,5223,5455,5664,5872,6633,7290,7747,8233,8523,8700,9358,9610,9845,11452,12545,22685,32633,35696,56665,65896,69536,99999}
47   8014 {1,21,41,65,85,218,321,412,444,544,634,741,862,943,1122,1690,2155,2458,2845,3240,3610,3852,4410,4840,5223,5455,5664,5872,6633,7290,7747,8233,8523,8700,9358,9610,9845,10240,11452,12545,22685,32633,35696,56665,65896,69536,99999}
48   7636 {1,21,41,65,85,218,321,412,444,544,634,741,862,943,1122,1690,2155,2458,2845,3240,3610,3852,4410,4840,5223,5455,5664,5872,6250,6633,7290,7747,8233,8523,8700,9358,9610,9845,10240,11452,12545,22685,32633,35696,56665,65896,69536,99999}
49   7273 {1,21,41,65,85,218,321,412,444,544,634,741,862,943,1122,1690,2155,2458,2845,3240,3610,3852,4410,4840,5223,5455,5664,5872,6250,6633,7290,7653,7747,8233,8523,8700,9358,9610,9845,10240,11452,12545,22685,32633,35696,56665,65896,69536,99999}
50   6922 {1,21,41,65,85,124,218,321,412,444,544,634,741,862,943,1122,1690,2155,2458,2845,3240,3610,3852,4410,4840,5223,5455,5664,5872,6250,6633,7290,7653,7747,8233,8523,8700,9358,9610,9845,10240,11452,12545,22685,32633,35696,56665,65896,69536,99999}
51   6584 {1,21,41,65,85,124,218,321,412,444,544,634,741,862,943,1122,1440,1960,2155,2458,2845,3240,3610,3852,4410,4840,5223,5455,5664,5872,6250,6633,7290,7653,7747,8233,8523,8700,9358,9610,9845,10240,11452,12545,22685,32633,35696,56665,65896,69536,99999}
52   6283 {1,21,41,65,85,124,218,321,412,444,544,634,741,862,943,1122,1440,1960,2155,2458,2845,3240,3610,3852,4410,4840,5223,5412,5477,5664,5872,6250,6633,7290,7653,7747,8233,8523,8700,9358,9610,9845,10240,11452,12545,22685,32633,35696,56665,65896,69536,99999}
53   5983 {1,21,41,65,85,124,218,321,412,444,544,634,741,862,943,1122,1440,1960,2155,2458,2845,3240,3610,3852,4410,4840,5223,5412,5477,5664,5872,6250,6633,7290,7653,7747,8233,8523,8700,9000,9358,9610,9845,10240,11452,12545,22685,32633,35696,56665,65896,69536,99999}
54   5707 {1,21,41,65,85,124,218,321,412,444,544,634,741,862,943,1122,1440,1960,2155,2458,2845,3240,3610,3852,4410,4548,4840,5223,5412,5477,5664,5872,6250,6633,7290,7653,7747,8233,8523,8700,9000,9358,9610,9845,10240,11452,12545,22685,32633,35696,56665,65896,69536,99999}
55   5450 {1,21,41,65,85,124,218,321,412,441,478,544,634,741,862,943,1122,1440,1960,2155,2458,2845,3240,3610,3852,4410,4548,4840,5223,5412,5477,5664,5872,6250,6633,7290,7653,7747,8233,8523,8700,9000,9358,9610,9845,10240,11452,12545,22685,32633,35696,56665,65896,69536,99999}
56   5196 {1,21,41,65,85,124,218,321,412,441,478,544,634,741,862,943,1122,1440,1960,2155,2458,2845,3240,3610,3852,4410,4548,4840,5223,5412,5477,5664,5872,6250,6633,6760,7290,7653,7747,8233,8523,8700,9000,9358,9610,9845,10240,11452,12545,22685,32633,35696,56665,65896,69536,99999}
57   4946 {1,21,41,65,85,124,218,321,412,441,478,544,634,741,862,943,1122,1440,1690,1960,2155,2458,2845,3240,3610,3852,4410,4548,4840,5223,5412,5477,5664,5872,6250,6633,6760,7290,7653,7747,8233,8523,8700,9000,9358,9610,9845,10240,11452,12545,22685,32633,35696,56665,65896,69536,99999}
58   4722 {1,5,21,41,65,85,124,218,321,412,441,478,544,634,741,862,943,1122,1440,1690,1960,2155,2458,2845,3240,3610,3852,4410,4548,4840,5223,5412,5477,5664,5872,6250,6633,6760,7290,7653,7747,8233,8523,8700,9000,9358,9610,9845,10240,11452,12545,22685,32633,35696,56665,65896,69536,99999}
59   4536 {1,5,21,41,65,85,124,218,321,412,441,478,544,634,741,862,943,1122,1440,1690,1960,2155,2458,2845,3240,3610,3852,4410,4548,4840,5223,5412,5477,5664,5872,6250,6633,6760,7290,7653,7747,7840,8233,8523,8700,9000,9358,9610,9845,10240,11452,12545,22685,32633,35696,56665,65896,69536,99999}
60   4352 {1,5,21,41,65,85,124,218,321,412,441,478,544,634,741,848,872,951,1122,1440,1690,1960,2155,2458,2845,3240,3610,3852,4410,4548,4840,5223,5412,5477,5664,5872,6250,6633,6760,7290,7653,7747,7840,8233,8523,8700,9000,9358,9610,9845,10240,11452,12545,22685,32633,35696,56665,65896,69536,99999}
61   4172 {1,5,21,41,65,85,124,218,321,357,412,441,478,544,634,741,848,872,951,1122,1440,1690,1960,2155,2458,2845,3240,3610,3852,4410,4548,4840,5223,5412,5477,5664,5872,6250,6633,6760,7290,7653,7747,7840,8233,8523,8700,9000,9358,9610,9845,10240,11452,12545,22685,32633,35696,56665,65896,69536,99999}
62   3995 {1,5,21,41,65,85,124,218,321,357,412,441,478,544,634,741,848,872,951,1122,1440,1690,1960,2155,2458,2845,3240,3610,3852,4410,4548,4840,5223,5412,5477,5664,5872,6250,6633,6760,7290,7653,7747,7840,8233,8410,8523,8700,9000,9358,9610,9845,10240,11452,12545,22685,32633,35696,56665,65896,69536,99999}
63   3828 {1,5,21,41,65,85,124,218,321,357,412,441,478,544,634,741,848,872,943,985,1122,1440,1690,1960,2155,2458,2845,3240,3610,3852,4410,4548,4840,5223,5412,5477,5664,5872,6250,6633,6760,7290,7653,7747,7840,8233,8410,8523,8700,9000,9358,9610,9845,10240,11452,12545,22685,32633,35696,56665,65896,69536,99999}
64   3680 {1,5,21,41,65,85,124,218,321,357,412,441,478,544,634,741,848,872,943,985,1122,1440,1690,1960,2155,2458,2845,3240,3610,3852,4000,4410,4548,4840,5223,5412,5477,5664,5872,6250,6633,6760,7290,7653,7747,7840,8233,8410,8523,8700,9000,9358,9610,9845,10240,11452,12545,22685,32633,35696,56665,65896,69536,99999}
65   3545 {1,5,21,32,45,65,85,124,218,321,357,412,441,478,544,634,741,848,872,943,985,1122,1440,1690,1960,2155,2458,2845,3240,3610,3852,4000,4410,4548,4840,5223,5412,5477,5664,5872,6250,6633,6760,7290,7653,7747,7840,8233,8410,8523,8700,9000,9358,9610,9845,10240,11452,12545,22685,32633,35696,56665,65896,69536,99999}
66   3418 {1,5,21,32,45,65,85,124,218,321,357,412,441,478,544,634,741,848,872,943,985,1122,1440,1690,1960,2155,2458,2845,3240,3610,3852,4000,4410,4548,4840,5223,5412,5477,5664,5872,5999,6250,6633,6760,7290,7653,7747,7840,8233,8410,8523,8700,9000,9358,9610,9845,10240,11452,12545,22685,32633,35696,56665,65896,69536,99999}
```

The output started slowing down on the PC too much before it reached 100 rows (of the possible 375).

Answer (score 1):

This algorithm does not produce exact answers, but it allows very large data sets to be handled much faster than the [memoized algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167774/minimize-the-sum-of-errors-of-representative-integers/6049669#6049669) and with results that tends to be very close to the exact answer. Algorithm still needs improvement/debugging to prevent potential infinite loops in some cases, but that is not a deal-breaker since code can be added to stop that. Meanwhile, the alg excels with data sets too large to be managed by some other generally preferable algorithms (like the memoized alg answer submitted earlier). For example, on nearly 10,000 samples from the range [1-100000], k=500 is calculated in seconds on an old PC where the memo version appeared would take over an hour to do a much smaller k=90 on a much much smaller data set of size 375. For this kind of added performance, not getting the absolute lowest error sum is a very small price to pay. [I have not derived the quality of the results, but all comparisons made on data values where memo could keep up yielded not much over 10% worse, if that.]

```
/************************************************************
This program can be compiled and run (eg, on Linux):
$ gcc -std=c99 fast-inexact.c -o fast-inexact
$ .fast-inexact
************************************************************/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

//a: Data set of values. Add extra large number at the end

int a[]={
10,40,90,160,250,360,490,640,810,1000,1210,1440,1690,1960,2250,2560,2890,3240,3610,4000,4410,
4840,5290,5760,6250,6760,7290,7840,8410,9000,9610,10240,99999,
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,
24,24,14,12,41,51,21,41,41,848,21,  547,3,2,888,4,1,66,5,4,2,11,742,
95,25,365,52,441,874,51,2,145,254,24,245,54,21,87,98,65,32,25,14,
25,36,25,14,47,58,58,69,85,74,71,82,82,93,93,93,12,12,45,78,78,985,
412,74,3,62,125,458,658,147,432,124,328,952,635,368,634,637,874,
124,35,23,65,896,21,41,745,49,2,7,8,4,8,7,2,6,5,6,9,8,9,6,5,9,5,9,
5,9,11,41,5,24,98,78,45,54,65,32,21,12,18,38,48,68,78,75,72,95,92,65,
55,5,87,412,158,654,219,943,218,952,357,753,159,951,485,862,1,741,22,
444,452,487,478,478,495,456,444,141,238,9,445,421,441,444,436,478,51,
24,24,24,24,24,24,247,741,98,99,999,111,444,323,33,5,5,5,85,85,85,85,
654,456,5,4,566,445,5664,45,4556,45,5,6,5,4,56,66,5,456,5,45,6,68,7653,
434,4,6,7,689,78,8,99,8700,344,65,45,8,899,86,65,3,422,3,4,3,4,7,68,
544,454,545,65,4,6,878,423,64,97,8778,5456,5486,5485,545,5455,4548,81,
999,8233,5223,8741,7747,7756,54,7884,5477,89,332,5999,9861,12545,9852,
11452,5482,9358,9845,577,884,5589,5412,3669,32,6699,396,9629,953,321,
45,5484,588,5872,85,872,87,1122,884,2458,471,22685,955,2845,6852,589,
5896,2521,35696,5236,32633,56665,6633,326,5486,5487,8541,5495,2155,3,
8523,65896,3852,5685,69536,
1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,
  //375

54,5451,545,54,885,855,8621,5,23,7,54,89,3,8545,196,35338,6412,5338,35512,8545,55483,3548,34878,37846,1545,2489,24534,84234,56465,8643,454,8,548,78,454,85,44,54564,87,85,45,48,54,564,67564,8945,864,54564,864,5453,554,7894,65456,45,5489,8424,84248,543,5454,82,54548,44,54654,8454,54,684,54,34,8,454,87,84,4,548,45456,48454,86465,4,454,45,4445,4564,484,4564,64654,56456,54,45,121,2851,15,248,24853,845,8485,384,3484,3484,3853,183,4835,83545,82,1851,6851,854,83,48434,87,34,854,943,849,468,4654,97,35,494,6549,878,65,2184,4845,4564,64,8,44,84,5,4454,4845,484,8513,897,47,8789,764,54,454,54894,454,842,181,54,81348,4518,548,51,813,1851,1841,5484,51,8431,8484,5487,79,4,31,31,84,87,74111,1,7272,7814,18,781,1,7,823,27872,8,8178,4156,485,184,84,45,18,75,18,715,48,78174,6541,8,54,8,41,8,4564,187,154,841,9,4194,53,4194,15,48,941,48,941,5,489,7415,41,49,41,54,54545,494,15,98,4189,5641,841,5145,41,416,48,414,4,841,5414,61,41,9891,61,169,19,1989,173,48154,56116,187,191,61,61418,8719,8187,51842,815,4815,4984,5,484,15,4897,18,4151,81,8941,549,1,5498,15,89,12,4,97,97,1,591,519,1,51,9,15,1655,65,2,3214,2365,8,77899,6565,6589,586,5,66,5,23669,5,9,59,9,8,569,3,3,6,96,99,955,5,96,9595,95,629,8971,81,5715,45,141,4819,84,518,81,87,2,41,5,98,41,54,9415,49,841,54,591,54,918,781,794,1221,2891,5,19878,154,9,4154,94,1518,41,49,415,49,15,4541,954,78,219,45,4515,49,9187,1549,15,985,14984,1597,91978,1541,41,5491,54197,815,914,91,78195,4179,1984,971,54,91,5198,71914,97,194,914,59419,49,4194,941,94191,41,9419,1941,914,9149,4191,1,19149,4949,454,141,1,9,489,415,4941,9841,24,8941,54,5915,198,419,24949,194,8545,4591,5498,714,54,984,5491,54,978,154,978,154,91495,41945,49,41954,8,154,94,149,4594,54,98,154,594,984,815,45,9148,4191,19,84,15,1,948,7897,184,5419,71,4194,8419,41984,954,54,1941,81798,789,459,45,4198,787,184,941,921,987,181,541,48,971,894,9145,594,19,78,48,4984,184,945,4,194,19849,454,978,4154,944,84154,9871,8489,4154,841,8945,198,710,45,4,51,541,984,982,1954,81,491,2465,498,5419,7481,5497,8515,498,4154,979,871,41,148,11971,184,94145,498,15,48,154,9418,41894,815,494,145,419,8,151,25,18940,5415,64348,74851,541,9481,24,9841,2,498,124,91,594,34614,64,8491,456,4164,81,3496,494,324,16498,15,4917,9841,546,4841,546,484,54541,654,81,246,518,4841,65,486,4165,4654,8415,4646,846,41654,864,165,45,4188,165,481,31,354,9415,491,549,484,87131,828,284,842,2,434,8434,64835,4313,143,48,35,498,7,154,8,7897,7154,654,987,564,3546,8789,715,4684,864,234,864,615,467,89,135,4198,7,654,64,189,7817,56,4,654,98,465,46,48,4,354,96,8413,54,8,768,45,165,46,81,654,3,48,7,41,54,6,71654,5618,745,4687,56461,8415,46841,654,18415,4641,684,8641,654,6848,
  //1030 data points where 0 sum was reached around k=700

91971,84841,7108,25538,61927,311,13293,49323,82575,42047,42621,4528,33492,40233,8207,19313,17418,20046,97930,91319,21352,75522,80884,92887,3172,3402,30154,53295,45129,64875,76120,95241,75935,50600,14969,24058,64668,10739,74264,82103,95766,81604,31825,48253,98824,53223,50979,74839,22673,6901,6628,40582,11625,16851,74329,34832,99379,67076,64535,32430,87878,39846,87266,94771,68911,30598,78570,11443,96418,82912,14659,57422,88738,73430,37122,14757,65752,64413,55350,47566,40052,5269,63245,91024,62122,96172,73761,32491,9914,22246,56477,72743,31766,539,8060,51233,94746,38936,82773,4027,49755,75621,27878,36503,63731,96923,93088,71466,7829,91854,96506,5351,9372,792,8237,29526,10003,45061,84050,64869,44551,18686,31130,92931,77843,257,81465,33118,41736,19277,23252,95069,38862,84583,1510,78924,52875,83591,88760,51204,55668,31803,28820,72180,85375,31097,61709,65438,76378,50339,69786,24471,37894,62870,61760,37134,19589,41610,54127,65701,23447,47115,77960,13598,42731,76482,51722,53980,83969,68876,28247,64097,74556,89852,32215,28318,66235,62950,5848,45470,40770,50000,20546,47738,5013,56026,69247,9403,14276,78600,52114,49300,57225,70920,41405,25704,72529,85561,95069,24490,22578,66416,10333,42579,7541,34835,89226,88650,29651,87181,47493,73420,73326,86056,96184,881,3074,34043,12385,62809,32617,30558,47161,95675,18317,95487,1691,30156,70901,86281,29738,59373,94311,11038,62245,98438,48944,35946,67426,98144,37638,39288,90091,2419,74368,5501,53487,4721,45268,92114,77645,92420,55346,24469,10418,80834,72980,57352,54643,47955,28398,59555,4432,64450,94353,18022,7363,88904,18304,75731,28145,77099,37077,51892,77769,78618,58440,76279,93078,66569,40061,11341,95239,42097,34627,455,45190,15006,70919,28975,52242,94947,81103,98508,18289,49883,93925,10329,28593,59948,62807,53107,82485,46257,99603,81315,69200,57179,81100,70139,56208,71697,58216,18287,56682,80797,74856,68581,24932,56111,79553,44985,1078,33601,5052,46698,58454,21591,22216,75724,51901,19814,34312,93688,12404,1472,74226,42104,88751,74560,27770,52677,1257,3921,14543,38065,62154,80166,41952,83753,27875,96367,46870,56989,70061,29349,30417,14600,15638,9381,12672,32427,52193,63465,21644,79884,1788,84165,86538,32588,14481,62895,18922,17814,52043,27770,90651,30220,54177,684,12877,79534,9521,9151,62696,49504,17889,92016,34501,79437,49929,35694,79281,81751,61146,37207,14690,88139,71934,37867,42414,14138,68956,66459,78179,98301,41906,28393,66701,39038,98593,78928,19123,89097,7903,86555,7229,72289,30837,26828,75810,85795,52580,23946,52315,75066,6195,6247,10422,36205,85037,85639,37868,40653,13242,14990,17400,87468,33841,76043,15413,52200,15840,43988,4222,1163,97877,5894,27907,49478,82287,62434,88319,1326,96296,19314,63080,94678,65175,46033,18353,721,50185,87762,48604,70941,57076,15778,83744,24345,72384,93133,60848,51265,34558,58951,16594,45325,19575,41243,4129,36254,47318,68398,85336,10464,81489,49839,17483,40148,36113,1869,68571,90880,26744,26872,80029,40512,50642,85233,39595,61899,73401,33864,32744,45026,35147,62806,66004,75647,32795,25836,22709,46475,18975,89237,63503,37520,62019,72519,66694,78254,11971,26555,38208,51235,82437,73811,30071,60979,42083,59457,17922,53300,69295,14213,79140,14106,93565,39018,98767,12898,19065,99290,55406,96661,81503,17804,17835,45522,36121,15560,90373,29672,82686,95100,85898,30209,39965,18232,96036,83814,67533,31902,91084,43548,81247,34779,24890,45285,10364,29152,94940,1995,28647,63798,74587,51510,61728,52559,95367,41582,56753,92546,45668,73055,76292,80820,71398,87558,10149,25260,95802,56610,94918,65816,83004,32247,89064,94486,43603,91064,9278,44821,43852,46724,55095,8366,4778,36327,75601,71599,3061,64696,56375,58868,1881,13519,7193,3729,55724,98000,686,20422,84697,6823,99729,51581,9345,3230,33531,62041,75483,78380,13008,92322,73680,95761,3407,73779,1497,25348,4410,4715,97954,27151,96981,33027,16691,4754,50716,26714,15603,3877,63828,2177,78364,78663,90410,32799,40001,88635,31521,62240,71126,88550,45596,35836,30578,14734,48055,78423,99670,66613,25034,16271,95578,39832,59491,64164,90110,24612,94666,98316,36945,84526,23957,35914,74261,10148,89869,7362,96525,28747,19389,54348,30954,83866,24346,62858,96355,25336,89159,17438,19877,26213,67260,19395,50133,17429,80909,44168,77546,44149,40791,21306,59121,22933,97532,24283,47625,60143,50324,31150,79093,34412,15694,57816,56400,30645,44351,91535,47481,71120,45186,25358,96844,2731,37108,15691,10876,85188,81006,56378,7416,80928,73845,50342,33962,45379,14001,62637,45,66328,28684,75003,63335,81237,31773,34202,32170,51647,64902,65287,23594,39435,72560,25085,34321,96756,31878,39290,10456,313,58353,87017,45851,46863,88919,38035,94970,67059,21063,13281,91385,94599,5249,34230,96221,35681,18889,64631,49931,51949,23519,37007,59540,76583,70018,97867,98583,94493,13835,55055,56230,57409,48797,81045,97777,38919,4967,75806,36522,29159,64195,58832,51397,5911,47348,72203,31621,61132,32046,47295,81259,92105,61855,46985,8173,15735,16105,14233,36084,27771,77334,39122,50253,25481,17826,63048,64197,80649,172,94257,41669,22848,45634,72586,11604,36415,75842,95214,81968,86722,8491,5522,778,68350,83144,72919,27675,98142,63391,76649,1091,61181,77909,10498,4311,1144,73887,86234,49497,2192,89204,27685,19088,12111,74087,63381,72931,39497,22860,73816,96460,82602,26617,90907,742,77501,54128,6263,58682,81642,54077,13337,55144,73541,30715,98031,19841,26379,51787,48035,81621,81003,63135,71207,857,53082,49846,33006,69020,32600,28809,93781,27697,28789,84895,40154,42393,46255,83968,38531,59098,23078,2388,31081,47343,91678,12450,54226,9212,68542,55477,6778,75148,15625,15970,58963,76847,7532,43793,56065,6579,15151,54887,15814,80796,62039,38595,82848,30052,22450,42599,2606,11555,17245,8693,90166,98322,3856,43958,78906,24069,91181,74155,11157,26701,75147,79735,83698,59368,99053,27406,35721,38162,72535,90580,98451,36614,74207,57638,43118,31493,54616,3525,14593,70458,65804,2371,29952,95822,16967,46585,85324,44495,40046,40188,28571,49601,87926,46314,89084,54871,51785,30464,40750,88002,46775,99857,41941,70369,49355,82416,67822,88126,72305,68090,42573,6664,50620,8171,54154,64323,71018,70255,49214,19102,13961,38126,13767,75255,89885,24285,6784,45907,76710,69512,96761,36343,9178,43610,26232,20416,35417,79808,48812,1442,12738,14060,27780,73339,72251,22224,984,99484,3129,95242,5406,45172,93152,17698,79263,91020,2372,96955,93000,16632,24974,80075,22770,78679,52026,87169,97389,60924,95753,22470,73104,14341,89258,27802,15165,44009,16116,65558,26768,84349,42048,38158,69626,54520,6232,89607,70649,89678,64649,61427,73712,23429,60767,97914,19092,55872,67273,72611,17408,58426,45902,1158,3151,12460,6843,12175,39110,13795,48488,598,88102,62734,30051,85108,83685,4614,16221,89546,22251,33607,22389,28056,97714,97847,69668,14514,25876,47436,98820,80096,38333,73919,10210,53350,38424,71994,95426,16011,63218,46060,88059,54803,17782,4764,89636,75816,20450,71524,51424,66346,38996,51636,65503,35668,16180,35424,16688,71067,19510,20900,81505,44392,88822,66810,54956,22721,4020,55164,7768,53816,29369,97493,22693,50851,53883,40911,91519,8328,3488,89357,265,68837,37347,68925,53993,39617,21956,81340,90625,17603,82990,55479,96397,54300,90079,19013,58286,80248,93752,48825,87804,38548,82925,79145,68161,26215,27595,28166,84134,53883,72828,14699,57729,9756,21219,71888,58735,27888,77657,9862,29308,5713,10369,5132,16637,36379,74924,73424,7622,67815,44654,61976,37575,67544,41394,765,60364,48627,28929,35016,65876,16879,35727,58510,44848,68747,63314,45271,38285,19974,31022,46601,79594,28293,41943,93783,73472,25540,42352,12406,76008,60580,97316,35941,23328,63611,42353,32625,86073,50162,36848,48968,26200,44694,79594,18595,96664,3781,66827,18775,76745,23087,49444,9680,44804,1139,95993,35979,73285,78351,51555,55892,72987,919,6576,58724,74645,55748,15929,5263,9385,31276,81207,26297,13715,36839,23698,80161,78030,22099,23672,18946,52224,63113,52239,62193,69534,6218,9437,72951,26121,99384,89559,22585,41905,50820,17497,62181,95609,11040,48450,4672,19090,74922,25774,27276,59533,82413,90879,54002,1927,80107,48775,3426,13476,8,56421,57833,11826,84730,13248,44960,22347,77712,38664,51496,10446,26342,92613,2537,50518,15298,50077,95138,59074,38391,25995,51757,68041,45079,73503,44795,73578,73714,86823,85676,86652,24529,65036,8034,84053,27255,51289,41191,54733,32906,43556,99492,36724,54294,58745,21879,39742,9760,84910,89882,22040,74779,87799,6733,85094,51541,2561,42018,50703,77647,48273,51943,25317,76893,43156,11204,23775,31223,90188,61128,28268,90392,44615,8268,29091,49155,85684,99848,45164,39604,29565,7404,45835,49245,63540,86092,99420,29373,37648,26577,49013,58660,15547,88827,60902,28092,21057,57412,65051,95942,67104,62021,81178,64070,25825,74358,939,257,2738,85713,59958,34270,45916,48325,86031,68099,13435,96,26509,74600,67943,48462,59415,62719,63542,46788,33966,56201,74797,49645,34663,70653,13993,75123,64971,56299,24290,55613,17019,16469,10228,41530,65684,20980,5657,34485,74200,65094,45106,82980,23313,89679,78589,76463,44692,92419,28224,67769,79223,10358,12046,64508,5664,84873,98898,65128,22810,40006,78824,85890,28783,24195,88541,17804,77888,98005,3163,40585,37812,83540,65091,2368,10153,10123,67755,4906,26772,91241,61110,81443,96255,55859,82616,50686,39787,2824,67188,75051,72755,88297,70263,10886,52465,90967,67740,38048,41855,57897,36010,98311,39800,34970,61919,53605,35960,34556,75179,62847,99582,53397,64903,97681,21363,89165,18184,63832,93788,41877,73907,40862,72219,55696,34322,70520,86524,58044,96077,51867,68264,68773,42545,23291,87772,43135,35583,34601,78101,33345,33146,17877,55345,47317,93056,55095,65630,83641,32938,20800,94894,86836,18949,33463,96351,90210,15136,93306,57484,4970,44591,98902,99319,64390,71429,9453,10288,25967,27543,35135,10277,22490,95493,40130,69518,34173,68057,99926,85945,64916,85557,25386,77470,46018,32982,8214,45880,16878,64891,93415,13796,54925,65390,91184,73091,97527,20617,56281,20972,61849,6063,22834,23121,50132,23168,65229,36501,7732,61662,97901,80938,5449,4324,17177,98702,90374,47638,78220,8025,631,14868,7109,99196,81197,61445,13447,88088,61439,81253,11602,79082,91878,78818,23302,98516,17627,35548,90154,93396,36910,78363,42642,78977,42405,77288,36169,14039,62197,8267,34957,14627,80164,49675,44941,46282,38844,80471,92596,57433,129,85146,35443,63604,8925,2513,16232,75329,65547,12865,65564,40061,37036,2476,18330,67599,77393,27915,21717,39812,67331,39831,91457,82078,86552,84524,33187,78388,93499,31834,51610,48374,9599,62442,58001,79427,25427,10503,79516,447,67385,67312,58505,44860,57318,34878,5784,24556,75323,42995,80230,66273,70899,98707,35982,28881,77311,13652,56025,39197,99183,60848,78778,12611,55865,32717,30740,98863,41178,61939,7501,15980,32740,35422,11145,47642,95924,26318,2168,1409,43150,76210,83168,74739,80236,49366,56557,97408,79222,60346,18130,37973,34753,29330,6319,90128,81966,20999,93645,6116,58983,64143,64283,28777,72347,88576,31292,32646,60348,32715,27780,57558,71558,62441,13266,17590,44902,70808,47002,35206,76340,61551,21960,23786,90629,38566,37365,31258,7344,89896,68418,32815,88560,1462,20635,98402,15486,87818,87832,36665,62422,19706,36102,59077,73157,88408,62456,94333,70225,5552,24127,22076,11571,53084,13717,63016,69793,18229,59206,5782,57379,89482,91636,32108,36221,34750,75596,45483,42593,34406,5029,18772,57724,84624,39233,86922,77772,79550,46276,51367,81047,3458,57390,26930,10328,59690,9573,24463,84201,38847,23755,11125,21505,48379,61368,21367,57139,84731,655,79392,8614,574,39349,68808,91270,98549,33131,12817,91148,95310,90468,67711,69769,23201,54384,94404,70804,1585,8258,46100,64826,22817,47627,40503,7975,62228,2710,71282,16290,73345,9938,11950,57669,2767,47660,95717,4262,87231,23613,3132,5303,35138,15020,78273,55237,44423,43500,60718,8549,35593,34035,87978,94337,43352,66386,24438,4444,99250,15905,7122,12769,9057,38677,31656,91946,36395,6718,17485,60118,28635,16146,62946,37135,31640,81708,28255,76004,97645,67914,42872,64750,74295,54037,32473,77988,34434,87058,97884,71812,99386,59090,54572,94425,88778,26076,81966,74456,58589,75413,95109,35565,47090,62943,21610,15980,51616,83195,68938,77421,95579,43972,33475,80601,75068,71451,46172,53235,10594,229,14538,15779,3535,18792,74958,52376,39650,78112,30435,94447,23664,53290,14297,36564,57415,42577,62973,60178,54379,23471,86489,62865,63912,73881,27530,83805,88588,50955,79897,13092,25428,21032,55713,59695,44564,91593,38587,88118,40408,3458,52854,31271,82336,65550,75963,6379,94470,95815,57597,93874,49015,2623,78929,3542,96688,85728,93123,63370,93923,76560,81218,49577,40321,83277,75622,40868,20647,46612,53977,72510,27750,35045,37285,27490,11203,31005,67918,16305,66145,40471,68625,23301,84038,20189,36517,98936,39855,69536,39650,69495,4564,22889,54425,52056,70852,2908,50233,74545,75399,24963,43468,48828,24219,51897,9941,2651,36619,17298,43353,88712,82010,31618,63076,36919,84544,79994,83762,88616,25184,25358,90200,24379,1593,4588,99452,57834,24314,49316,55537,35259,88574,38989,461,34754,4295,90437,72079,88103,58951,94197,6143,66948,69639,73061,73794,18524,36274,36020,97571,22422,94371,55337,70290,23719,53295,26714,29618,44899,26361,6649,77299,54330,43848,2630,5462,43877,47405,17621,71980,48556,69593,10270,46270,96883,82522,97178,9692,38037,86735,12843,18547,90318,86142,36102,54725,67779,33960,70407,88337,68586,7416,32155,69809,76500,70306,61447,80616,15737,87763,27999,73308,44107,53341,12657,44004,61361,90129,11435,7085,83481,28657,86953,13639,35151,52055,98933,42279,8555,15128,98397,55654,21379,32574,97085,84159,36599,94225,9609,46510,85077,48658,2029,91337,35690,89749,37788,70610,10988,40687,76143,75614,96737,58393,53231,6038,72579,98172,68388,22202,75978,76105,62423,49984,89596,86908,52089,45258,42748,81535,12974,16453,27924,36973,55034,86639,71309,45107,17565,24195,39749,79635,82267,38262,24281,66895,22641,63707,26083,77311,11325,69871,66911,58230,47237,86189,86797,39368,87093,27872,48833,92246,72298,38752,73197,52211,18861,26297,48056,20065,65745,77341,96440,93208,79154,17581,91398,79828,59172,11980,31520,93006,90766,66947,25505,25662,51023,65611,68719,63162,26980,62111,33503,1486,79944,60541,97670,31407,32663,2175,36753,80740,98049,11417,70007,45707,20439,23306,81475,18876,79912,99032,38020,70540,25705,47679,54785,65712,60704,17881,63622,70029,11128,12249,58989,86318,73313,81666,73660,35613,13506,18101,38049,72504,24305,72834,59070,86071,40740,89168,78606,20938,68498,4058,52276,17717,47543,69021,7429,70137,18260,99292,15612,36939,26462,98679,74311,89545,57406,22151,89872,75116,77927,708,45972,38956,82904,59329,66204,82768,20511,72448,62524,87094,72666,36882,35918,2861,47804,24993,4741,22743,21102,23629,94258,42562,64222,95958,20392,86930,90823,49038,70593,4626,44967,17031,30479,24644,445,39185,42883,78137,45683,17756,54827,56304,89580,68790,85188,79520,52051,50933,47318,99246,22670,38591,17499,28045,35897,10805,97972,59912,69796,47591,87583,71044,9546,60276,47273,54530,64316,78565,55598,85509,68537,15822,53298,6913,78820,34806,23461,284,67945,80858,85813,9375,38770,83815,85870,58022,85829,52337,86324,79505,83821,11453,90476,36126,3399,87985,3568,71839,500,4500,88954,76271,29306,7336,56562,80863,6939,11635,25426,90038,43766,11098,1442,14002,76769,11714,51146,37615,88888,44783,94305,70233,19140,88140,54117,69619,93691,63860,64113,38961,85274,83126,16814,59257,35115,47597,69520,86248,82673,58660,20880,41290,12433,47215,34085,89592,19558,40045,76312,14199,74436,86458,70215,91487,71433,842,52231,56386,50702,87931,25493,45389,77371,50364,58718,16481,47618,59975,34313,10748,46240,47191,67951,40516,61168,65880,38343,23913,43060,82008,62035,75518,40273,83224,93027,21877,77435,88307,71632,1290,632,50128,9736,88768,37080,45712,4640,24781,93644,30882,33452,46119,42674,37702,89906,3306,6481,4953,12024,59540,87372,48001,2808,86196,55303,4471,18788,16408,59537,96648,92719,33499,6722,48955,33862,37879,13396,51670,43929,3939,48079,7524,30503,53480,5113,51939,94524,21433,17288,99724,16560,84499,11638,87050,60679,30010,88386,23716,28451,49719,22809,4109,25706,42582,55513,37422,47324,48847,53170,43576,84234,70617,40713,83624,15968,10641,63638,32104,65516,91641,5415,11173,5659,26470,28816,5998,33061,37595,42178,89808,43363,5269,23750,61805,51709,85293,88466,97116,4958,53628,55383,7265,38854,41885,40104,76385,44247,11543,30538,2550,62201,6462,67803,58608,73861,24575,92339,66125,11831,69331,66295,92341,93284,77231,44467,36331,47688,61093,39930,11186,17004,50702,88419,87123,4120,75947,73915,56934,53118,9829,22476,31866,85915,78365,50359,87479,80483,43982,24880,11468,69964,23984,20071,95228,63841,65270,25149,25133,58416,90652,74823,57118,96185,80077,2593,71310,39144,50045,38367,99790,79818,24103,43742,15546,60521,37955,28865,40358,85080,82134,23407,26816,91597,55285,34872,40824,81081,96452,96514,19764,63241,8287,7009,94878,93697,19786,50498,812,16033,1477,5958,72682,24719,2862,24640,75466,72096,62615,59825,51657,88987,31905,7150,1124,89274,93786,93492,12603,77640,93879,50029,38429,46416,14540,60096,99854,53701,21337,14776,23149,88425,87612,14118,73275,95677,39736,3861,38363,43532,86976,15608,57283,51214,31728,86864,3893,27587,60312,59186,75516,88981,54955,51563,28305,65703,39850,31114,26250,3584,46705,77618,3806,65896,68972,86255,44699,33004,84586,3957,78670,42706,9693,82971,71501,40885,48798,242,43439,36694,26933,51184,3285,42256,95213,33537,49816,36308,90626,951,40183,83542,11529,28352,57885,13323,48035,12880,7877,91954,93393,52484,52896,23149,50824,21749,49257,22391,26697,86114,57421,78006,81506,93889,24402,6114,92508,14331,62855,31552,80177,74401,2284,59442,18156,14048,16802,43234,64081,10157,79349,27857,18695,43181,37814,81532,19176,12963,37409,62303,51145,82240,82460,24582,65136,51998,26422,3929,13113,49884,43757,5622,55423,97518,40118,86731,92631,27205,90926,96293,52068,23709,65996,26947,96154,90337,7128,61897,4087,1991,23993,72488,86899,79374,11324,65148,88418,54336,12508,45647,16415,24710,13391,49148,95397,52338,72425,10023,68818,69355,49133,6885,23866,96638,15108,4489,91949,27222,5337,23033,81313,53666,77066,51356,802,88481,73212,23401,9683,58821,34532,78650,75983,37081,45008,45518,28358,73269,62559,78852,33061,22244,40088,55471,93262,69180,69656,21966,99573,56305,78275,32777,50891,53474,49154,20607,2148,90109,39213,57031,23313,61937,36049,86539,44626,86424,72189,79772,35617,2010,10973,83124,61716,63266,76741,70735,42465,12545,50465,55141,56235,27373,11852,54391,62949,35903,11676,42076,94570,98170,21346,17823,34684,94320,5241,17876,22221,86826,60898,6228,79471,82826,96582,25270,22077,78881,45064,40919,62442,72087,63729,34985,31142,15176,70720,52435,18755,39650,40171,90443,81261,36559,81823,67630,78532,56197,16870,77809,5654,18834,96386,3089,20120,95531,2744,78053,81987,16283,43645,86248,80595,11559,18234,59452,81379,53882,15148,5439,15665,98296,52359,40524,34081,
  //+8000 rand ...   cut to about 3000 to fit stackoverflow posting limits
};

//numofa: size of data set

int numofa=sizeof(a)/sizeof(int);

//Sort in increasing order. Used by slow algo to be not nearly as slow.

int sortfunc (const void *a, const void *b) {
    return (*(int *)a - *(int *)b);
}

// Given 3 adjacent k values. Re-calculates the middle k value where (changing only this middle k value) the sum of the error on its left and error on its right is minimized (ie, ke[left] and ke[middle] are minimized).

int minimize_error_3(int *k, int *kai, int64_t *ke, const int left, const int middle, const int right) {
    int64_t minerr=-1;
    int64_t tmperr;
    int64_t l_e=0, e=0;  //not necessary to save errors by parts in general but
    long minidx=kai[left]+1;
//printf ("%d %d %d %d ",k[middle], left, middle, right);
    for (int i=kai[left]; i<kai[right]; i++) {
        tmperr=0;
        for (int j=kai[left]+1; j<i; j++) {   //int j=kai[left]
            tmperr+=a[j]-a[kai[left]];
        }
        e=tmperr;
        for (int j=i+1; j<kai[right]; j++) {
            tmperr+=a[j]-a[i];
        }
        if (minerr==-1)
            minerr=tmperr;
        if (tmperr<minerr) {
            minerr=tmperr;
            minidx=i;
            l_e=e;
        }
    }
    ke[left]=l_e;
    ke[middle]=minerr>-1?minerr-l_e:0;
    kai[middle]=minidx;
    k[middle]=a[minidx];
//printf ("%d %d %d.%d   ",ke[left], ke[middle], k[middle], minidx);
    return 0;
}

int evenstartitercycles (int numofk) {
    char *str, *str2;
    int i, idx, err;
    int done, moved;
    int *k, *kai, *k_old;
    int64_t *ke;

    qsort(a,numofa,sizeof(int),sortfunc);
    k=(int *) calloc(numofk,sizeof(int));
    kai=(int *) malloc(numofk*sizeof(int));
    k_old=(int *) malloc(numofk*sizeof(int));
    ke=(int64_t *) calloc(numofk,sizeof(int64_t));
    k[0]=a[0];
    kai[0]=0;
    k_old[0]=k[0];
    for (int i=1; i<numofk-1; i++) {
        k[i]=a[(numofa*i)/(numofk-1)];
        kai[i]=(numofa*i)/(numofk-1);
        k_old[i]=k[i];
    }
    k[numofk-1]=a[numofa-1];
    kai[numofk-1]=numofa-1;
    k_old[numofk-1]=k[numofk-1];
    ke[numofk-1]=0;    //already 0
    i=0;
    moved=1;
int at_end=0;
int min_x=k[2]-k[1];    //1 doing infin loop  0 ok but violates rule
int min_xi=1;    //1 doing infin loop  0 ok but violates rule
int max_e=-1;
int max_ei=0;

    while (!at_end || moved) {
        if (i==0) {
            moved=0;
            at_end=0;
            min_x=k[2]-k[1];  //?
            min_xi=1;
            max_e=-1;  //?
            max_ei=0;
        }
        minimize_error_3(k, kai, ke, i, i+1, i+2);
        if (i>0) {
            if (k[i+1]-k[i]<min_x) {
                min_x=k[i+1]-k[i];
                min_xi=i;
            }
            if (ke[i]>max_e && i>min_xi+1) {
                max_e=ke[i];
                max_ei=i;
            }
            //later do going to left version
        }
        if (k[i+1]!=k_old[i+1]) {
            moved=1;
            k_old[i+1]=k[i+1];
        }
        if (i<numofk-3) {
            i++;
        } else {
            if (ke[i+1]>max_e && i+1>min_xi) {
                max_e=ke[i+1];
                max_ei=i+1;
            }
            //here see if can gain from shifting around some
            if (max_ei>min_xi+3 && .1*ke[min_xi]*(k[min_xi]-k[min_xi-1])<max_e) {       //fix the +3 to make it unnec???  .3??
//printf("1:%d %d %d %d    ",min_x,min_xi,max_e,max_ei);
                moved=1;
                for (int i=min_xi; i<max_ei; i++) {
                    k[i]=a[kai[i+1]];
                    kai[i]=kai[i+1];
                }
                k[max_ei]=a[++kai[max_ei]];
            }
            i=0;
            at_end=1;
        }
    }
    err=0;
    for (int i=0; i<numofk; i++)
        err+=ke[i];
    str=(char *) calloc(numofk,20);
    for (int i=0; i<numofk; i++)
        sprintf (str+strlen(str),"%d,",k[i]);
    str2=(char *) calloc(numofk,20);
    for (int i=0; i<numofk; i++)
        sprintf (str2+strlen(str2),"%d,",(int)ke[i]);
    printf ("\nevenstartitercycles(%d): The mininum error was %d, found at, k={%s} with error parts={%s} ",numofk,err,str,str2);
    free(str);
    free(str2);
    return 0;
}

int main (int x, char **y) {
    int t; //to track unique num of data if want this feature
    int kmax;

    qsort(a,numofa,sizeof(int),sortfunc);
    t=1;
    for (int i=1; i<numofa; i++)
        if (a[i]!=a[i-1]) {
            t++;
        }
    kmax=t; //t is value where we can reach 0 err sum for first time
    kmax=numofa; //this will give many cases of 0 sum error for data sets that have many repeated data points.
    for (int i=3; i<=kmax; i++) {
        evenstartitercycles(i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This <strike>is</strike> is similar to one-dimensional [*k*-medians clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-medians_clustering).

The DP I suggested previously won't work; I think we need a table from (n', k', i) to the optimal solution on D<sub>1</sub> ≤ … ≤ D<sub>n'</sub> with k' representatives of which the greatest is i. Given the bounds on D, the running time is on the order of n<sup>2</sup> k with a very large constant, so you should probably adapt one of the heuristics that people use for *k*-means.

Comment: can you explain it in more detail?

Comment: how can we calculate DP[k+1][i] from DP[k][i-1] and DP[k][i] ?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into [Ward's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User%3aMathstat/Ward%27s_method) using your particular distance function.

Answer (score 0):

one first obvious point is that your Rs must be chosen amongst your Ds. (if you choose an R that is any D - 1 (but not another D), you'll improve the answer by incrementing your R by 1)

a second point is that your last R is useless and its error will always be 0