# Minimizing time in transit

Tags: algorithm, optimization, shortest-path

[Updates at bottom (**including solution source code**)]

I have a challenging business problem that a computer can help solve.

Along a mountainous region flows a long winding river with strong currents. Along certain parts of the river are plots of environmentally sensitive land suitable for growing a particular type of rare fruit that is in very high demand. Once field laborers harvest the fruit, the clock starts ticking to get the fruit to a processing plant. It's very costly to try and send the fruits upstream or over land or air. By far the most cost effective mechanism to ship them to the plant is downstream in containers powered solely by the river's constant current. We have the capacity to build 10 processing plants and need to locate these along the river to minimize the total time the fruits spend in transit. The fruits can take however long before reaching the nearest downstream plant but that time directly hurts the price at which they can be sold. Effectively, we want to minimize the sum of the distances to the nearest respective downstream plant. A plant can be located as little as 0 meters downstream from a fruit access point.

The question is: In order to maximize profits, how far up the river should we build the 10 processing plants if we have found 32 fruit growing regions, where the regions' distances upstream from the base of the river are (in meters):
10, 40, 90, 160, 250, 360, 490, ... (n^2)*10 ... 9000, 9610, 10320?

*[It is hoped that all work going towards solving this problem and towards creating similar problems and usage scenarios can help raise awareness about and generate popular resistance towards the damaging and stifling nature of software/business method patents (to whatever degree those patents might be believed to be legal within a locality).]*

UPDATES

---

Update1: Forgot to add: I believe this question is a special case of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167774/minimize-the-sum-of-errors-of-representative-integers/5958885#5958885).

Update2: One algorithm I wrote gives an answer in a fraction of a second, and I believe is rather good (but it's not yet stable across sample values). I'll give more details later, but the short is as follows. Place the plants at equal spacings. Cycle over all the inner plants where at each plant you recalculate its position by testing every location between its two neighbors until the problem is solved within that space (greedy algorithm). So you optimize plant 2 holding 1 and 3 fixed. Then plant 3 holding 2 and 4 fixed... When you reach the end, you cycle back and repeat until you go a full cycle where every processing plant's recalculated position stops varying.. also at the end of each cycle, you try to move processing plants that are crowded next to each other and are all near each others' fruit dumps into a region that has fruit dumps far away. There are many ways to vary the details and hence the exact answer produced. I have other candidate algorithms, but all have glitches. [I'll post code later.] Just as Mike Dunlavey mentioned below, we likely just want "good enough".

To give an idea of what might be a "good enough" result:

```
10010 total length of travel from 32 locations to plants at 
{10,490,1210,1960,2890,4000,5290,6760,8410,9610}
```

Update3: mhum gave the correct exact solution first but did not (yet) post a program or algorithm, so I wrote one up that yields the same values.

```
/************************************************************
This program can be compiled and run (eg, on Linux):
$ gcc -std=c99 processing-plants.c -o processing-plants
$ ./processing-plants
************************************************************/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//a: Data set of values. Add extra large number at the end

int a[]={
10,40,90,160,250,360,490,640,810,1000,1210,1440,1690,1960,2250,2560,2890,3240,3610,4000,4410,4840,5290,5760,6250,6760,7290,7840,8410,9000,9610,10240,99999
};

//numofa: size of data set

int numofa=sizeof(a)/sizeof(int);

//a2: will hold (pt to) unique data from a and in sorted order.

int *a2;

//max: size of a2

int max;

//num_fixed_loc: at 10 gives the solution for 10 plants

int num_fixed_loc;

//xx: holds index values of a2 from the lowest error winner of each cycle memoized. accessed via memoized offset value. Winner is based off lowest error sum from left boundary upto right ending boundary.
//FIX: to be dynamically sized.

int xx[1000000];

//xx_last: how much of xx has been used up

int xx_last=0;

//SavedBundle: data type to "hold" memoized values needed (total traval distance and plant locations) 

typedef struct _SavedBundle {
    long e;
    int xx_offset;
} SavedBundle;

//sb: (pts to) lookup table of all calculated values memoized

SavedBundle *sb;  //holds winning values being memoized

//Sort in increasing order.

int sortfunc (const void *a, const void *b) {
    return (*(int *)a - *(int *)b);
}

/****************************
Most interesting code in here
****************************/

long full_memh(int l, int n) {
    long e;
    long e_min=-1;
    int ti;

    if (sb[l*max+n].e) {
        return sb[l*max+n].e;  //convenience passing
    }
    for (int i=l+1; i<max-1; i++) {
        e=0;
        //sum first part
        for (int j=l+1; j<i; j++) {
            e+=a2[j]-a2[l];
        }
        //sum second part
        if (n!=1) //general case, recursively
            e+=full_memh(i, n-1);
        else      //base case, iteratively
            for (int j=i+1; j<max-1; j++) {
                e+=a2[j]-a2[i];
            }
        if (e_min==-1) {
            e_min=e;
            ti=i;
        }
        if (e<e_min) {
            e_min=e;
            ti=i;
        }
    }
    sb[l*max+n].e=e_min;
    sb[l*max+n].xx_offset=xx_last;
    xx[xx_last]=ti;      //later add a test or a realloc, etc, if approp
    for (int i=0; i<n-1; i++) {
        xx[xx_last+(i+1)]=xx[sb[ti*max+(n-1)].xx_offset+i];
    }
    xx_last+=n;
    return e_min;
}

/*************************************************************
Call to calculate and print results for given number of plants
*************************************************************/

int full_memoization(int num_fixed_loc) {
    char *str;
    long errorsum;  //for convenience

    //Call recursive workhorse
    errorsum=full_memh(0, num_fixed_loc-2);
    //Now print
    str=(char *) malloc(num_fixed_loc*20+100);
    sprintf (str,"\n%4d %6d {%d,",num_fixed_loc-1,errorsum,a2[0]);
    for (int i=0; i<num_fixed_loc-2; i++)
        sprintf (str+strlen(str),"%d%c",a2[ xx[ sb[0*max+(num_fixed_loc-2)].xx_offset+i ] ], (i<num_fixed_loc-3)?',':'}');
    printf ("%s",str);
    return 0;
}

/**************************************************
Initialize and call for plant numbers of many sizes
**************************************************/

int main (int x, char **y) {
    int t;
    int i2;

    qsort(a,numofa,sizeof(int),sortfunc);
    t=1;
    for (int i=1; i<numofa; i++)
        if (a[i]!=a[i-1])
            t++;
    max=t;
    i2=1;
    a2=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*t);
    a2[0]=a[0];
    for (int i=1; i<numofa; i++)
        if (a[i]!=a[i-1]) {
            a2[i2++]=a[i];
        }
    sb = (SavedBundle *)calloc(sizeof(SavedBundle),max*max);
    for (int i=3; i<=max; i++) {
        full_memoization(i);
    }
    free(sb);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also forgetting to add the homework tag, I feel?

Comment: It's not the homework problem of anyone I know, but I suppose it could be. How does one write a challenge problem, to be documented on stackoverflow, that doesn't appear to be a "homework" problem?

Comment: Well it looks like a basic hill-climbing problem, for which my favorite method is [Metropolis-Hastings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis%E2%80%93Hastings_algorithm). What's all that business about patents?

Comment: @Mike Dunlavey, after reading the other problem, I coded a few algorithms (though they all currently have critical flaws of one sort or other). The "try all possibilities approach" may yield an exact answer to this question before next year, but changing 10 to something like 15 will push the running time way beyond my lifetime (at least on my PC). Other algorithms are almost instantaneous but give approximations. I'll post in the future with improved code and more details of these results (eg, {10,640,1210,1960,2890,4000,5290,6760,8410,9610} ). Others might want to post algorithms as well.

Comment: @Mike Dunlavey, the patent business is a sad reality. Anyone with cash and a disrespect for peers and progress can find many use cases of concepts and algorithms applied to some problem in order to try and get a 20 year monopoly. I have trouble collaborating without this haunting constantly coming up in my mind. All it takes by law is something "non-obvious to a person having ordinary skill in the art" in order to stifle commerce, research, self-expression, you name it.

Comment: @Jose_X: Ok, I'm glad I _did_ include the question mark. Answering your question: I'd loose the scenic route and ditto proza, and include some code. Otherwise, http://math.stackexchange.com/ would seem like a good place to look

Comment: @sehe, thanks for the tips. I'll keep an eye on math.stackexchange.com though an important intent with this question is to seek a software algorithm that can be used in practice (engineering). I took the scenic route in order to build a real world "application" of a math problem because this is the sort of demented angle taken by numerous patent attorneys and by those others who stand behind software and other process patents. .. I'll go add the "patent" tag to this question.

Comment: @Jose_X: I'm married to a patent information specialist so I can appreciate the humor!

Comment: @Jose_X: Metropolis-Hastings is not a try-all-possibilities approach. It is a markov-chain method that generates sample answers preferentially in the vicinity of the optimum, and the dispersion of the samples reflects the flatness of the top of the hill. It does not claim to find the "true optimum", and for most applications an approximate optimum is effectively as good as an exact one. It is very effective at working in spaces of high dimensionality.

Comment: @Jose_X: Also, the method you describe rings another bell, [K-means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering). If you can choose an initial number of clusters, and put them in reasonably-separated initial places, it is very simple and effective.

Comment: Is the production from each plot assumed to be equal? You'd do something different if, say, the plot furthest upstream produces more than all the other plots combined.

Comment: @mhum, no variability of that kind or of any other. The problem to be solved is strictly about minimizing the total travel distance from each of the origin points to the nearest processing plant downstream. You might want to also read the link mentioned at the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I've made an error, here are exact solutions (obtained through a [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) approach):

```
N  Dist  Sites
2  60950 {10,4840}
3  40910 {10,2890,6760}
4  30270 {10,2250,4840,7840}
5  23650 {10,1690,3610,5760,8410}
6  19170 {10,1210,2560,4410,6250,8410}
7  15840 {10,1000,2250,3610,5290,7290,9000}
8  13330 {10,810,1960,3240,4410,5760,7290,9000}
9  11460 {10,810,1690,2890,4000,5290,6760,8410,9610}
10 9850  {10,640,1440,2250,3240,4410,5760,7290,8410,9610}
11 8460  {10,640,1440,2250,3240,4410,5290,6250,7290,8410,9610}
12 7350  {10,490,1210,1960,2890,3610,4410,5290,6250,7290,8410,9610}
13 6470  {10,490,1000,1690,2250,2890,3610,4410,5290,6250,7290,8410,9610}
14 5800  {10,360,810,1440,1960,2560,3240,4000,4840,5760,6760,7840,9000,10240}
15 5190  {10,360,810,1440,1960,2560,3240,4000,4840,5760,6760,7840,9000,9610,10240}
16 4610  {10,360,810,1210,1690,2250,2890,3610,4410,5290,6250,7290,8410,9000,9610,10240}
17 4060  {10,360,810,1210,1690,2250,2890,3610,4410,5290,6250,7290,7840,8410,9000,9610,10240}
18 3550  {10,360,810,1210,1690,2250,2890,3610,4410,5290,6250,6760,7290,7840,8410,9000,9610,10240}
19 3080  {10,360,810,1210,1690,2250,2890,3610,4410,5290,5760,6250,6760,7290,7840,8410,9000,9610,10240}
20 2640  {10,250,640,1000,1440,1960,2560,3240,4000,4840,5290,5760,6250,6760,7290,7840,8410,9000,9610,10240}
21 2230  {10,250,640,1000,1440,1960,2560,3240,4000,4410,4840,5290,5760,6250,6760,7290,7840,8410,9000,9610,10240}
22 1860  {10,250,640,1000,1440,1960,2560,3240,3610,4000,4410,4840,5290,5760,6250,6760,7290,7840,8410,9000,9610,10240}
23 1520  {10,250,490,810,1210,1690,2250,2890,3240,3610,4000,4410,4840,5290,5760,6250,6760,7290,7840,8410,9000,9610,10240}
24 1210  {10,250,490,810,1210,1690,2250,2560,2890,3240,3610,4000,4410,4840,5290,5760,6250,6760,7290,7840,8410,9000,9610,10240}
25 940   {10,250,490,810,1210,1690,1960,2250,2560,2890,3240,3610,4000,4410,4840,5290,5760,6250,6760,7290,7840,8410,9000,9610,10240}
26 710   {10,160,360,640,1000,1440,1690,1960,2250,2560,2890,3240,3610,4000,4410,4840,5290,5760,6250,6760,7290,7840,8410,9000,9610,10240}
27 500   {10,160,360,640,1000,1210,1440,1690,1960,2250,2560,2890,3240,3610,4000,4410,4840,5290,5760,6250,6760,7290,7840,8410,9000,9610,10240}
28 330   {10,160,360,640,810,1000,1210,1440,1690,1960,2250,2560,2890,3240,3610,4000,4410,4840,5290,5760,6250,6760,7290,7840,8410,9000,9610,10240}
29 200   {10,160,360,490,640,810,1000,1210,1440,1690,1960,2250,2560,2890,3240,3610,4000,4410,4840,5290,5760,6250,6760,7290,7840,8410,9000,9610,10240}
30 100   {10,90,250,360,490,640,810,1000,1210,1440,1690,1960,2250,2560,2890,3240,3610,4000,4410,4840,5290,5760,6250,6760,7290,7840,8410,9000,9610,10240}
31 30    {10,90,160,250,360,490,640,810,1000,1210,1440,1690,1960,2250,2560,2890,3240,3610,4000,4410,4840,5290,5760,6250,6760,7290,7840,8410,9000,9610,10240}
32 0     {10,40,90,160,250,360,490,640,810,1000,1210,1440,1690,1960,2250,2560,2890,3240,3610,4000,4410,4840,5290,5760,6250,6760,7290,7840,8410,9000,9610,10240}
```

Comment: On quick inspection, the numbers look to me to be about right. [I'll tentatively call this the winning answer]. Let me ask a couple of things. First, is your algorithm able to deal with any set of values for the "fruit" locations as long as these are bounded? This would include multiple fruit plots essentially at the same location (ie, production is xN). I assume you could adjust it easily if these cases were not met. The second question is whether you will post or link to the algorithm? Anyone who provides that info will have the more complete answer. Analysis of the code would be better yet.

Comment: BTW, it does seem like you would have a solution to that other problem I linked to. I don't know how to get in touch with the person who asked the question, but maybe someone with edit rights will be able to certify an answer to that one (if you provide your code or whatever it is the individual was asking for).

Comment: In Update3, I added an implementation that gives the same answer you provided. It leverages memoization. I may explain the details later on for those who might be interested. Feel free to post another algorithm as well (or critique, etc). And thanks for the extra motivation: for showing an exact solution was within reach but not posting the algorithm code. I may still return to the earlier algorithms I had to see if, once fixed, those have advantages over this one.

Answer (score 2):

Let me give you a simple example of a [Metropolis-Hastings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis%E2%80%93Hastings_algorithm) algorithm.
Suppose you have a state vector *x*, and a goodness-of-fit function *P(x)*, which can be any function you care to write.

Suppose you have a random distribution *Q* that you can use to modify the vector, such as `x' = x + N(0, 1) * sigma`, where N is a simple normal distribution about 0, and *sigma* is a standard deviation of your choosing.

```
p = P(x);
for (/* a lot of iterations */){
  // add x to a sample array
  // get the next sample
  x' = x + N(0,1) * sigma;
  p' = P(x');
  // if it is better, accept it
  if (p' > p){
    x = x';
    p = p';
  }
  // if it is not better
  else {
    // maybe accept it anyway
    if (Uniform(0,1) < (p' / p)){
      x = x';
      p = p';
    }
  }
}
```

Usually it is done with a burn-in time of maybe 1000 cycles, after which you start collecting samples. After another maybe 10,000 cycles, the average of the samples is what you take as an answer.

It requires diagnostics and tuning. Typically the samples are plotted, and what you are looking for is a "fuzzy caterpilar" plot that is stable (doesn't move around much) and has a high acceptance rate (very fuzzy). The main parameter you can play with is *sigma*.
If *sigma* is too small, the plot will be fuzzy but it will wander around.
If it is too large, the plot will not be fuzzy - it will have horizontal segments.
Often the starting vector *x* is chosen at random, and often multiple starting vectors are chosen, to see if they end up in the same place.

It is not necessary to vary all components of the state vector *x* at the same time. You can cycle through them, varying one at a time, or some such method.

Also, if you don't need the diagnostic plot, it may not be necessary to save the samples, but just calculate the average and variance on the fly.

In the applications I'm familiar with, P(x) is a measure of probability, and it is typically in log-space, so it can vary from 0 to negative infinity.
Then to do the "maybe accept" step it is `(exp(logp' - logp))`

Comment: When I get an opportunity, I thought to consider an algorithm within the program so as to internally vary weights on repeat trials and save some of the better values for reuse later under various contexts. That approach/feature does lend itself naturally to additional variations like what you described here of adding in a certain amount of random acceptance of parameters. My preference is to leverage insight into the particular problem to control the details of parameter variations, but, as long as a problem is not proven, adding in randomness can help build interesting unsought data pts.

Comment: @Jose_X: As you're seeing, it's flexible, and by accepting steps less good than what you have, you don't get trapped into local maxima.

Comment: Right, my way of dealing with local traps was to try to move points a bit far from each other. In fact, an infinite loop the program enters some times is almost surely (haven't spent time with the code yet) what I was trying to avoid: that a shift displacement is not far enough so the values resettle back into their old positions, triggering another round of shifting.